# Jquery animation on Firefox 7.0.1 lags

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, smoothing

Does anyone know why this very simple jquery animation works perfectly in some browsers like Chrome and seems to be bugged in Firefox 7.0.1?
Here's [a link](http://jquery_animation_bug.dcod.me/) to the animation.
If you try it in Firefox you'll see that the animation sometimes freezes then restarts.
As you can see the code is very simple, only one animation, no images, and inline CSS.

html:

```
<div id="content" style="position: relative;width: 500px;height: 500px;overflow: hidden;">
    <ul id="slider" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;">
        <li style="background-color: red;height: 500px;width: 500px;list-style-type: none;"></li>
        <li style="background-color: green;height: 500px;width: 500px;list-style-type: none;"></li>
        <li style="background-color: blue;height: 500px;width: 500px;list-style-type: none;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    to_move=$('#slider');
    to_move.animate({
       top: "-1000px"
    }, 15000,'linear');
});
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is Firefox's garbage collector kicking in every so often.

Via [Dave Mandelin's blog](http://blog.mozilla.com/dmandelin/2011/04/22/mozilla-javascript-2011/):

> Background on what GC is if you are not familiar: As a JavaScript
>   program runs, it creates objects, arrays, strings, and functions,
>   which take up memory. In order to not use up all your memory and
>   crash, the JS engine must be able to automatically discover which
>   objects are not in use anymore (so they are now “garbage”) and free
>   them up. This “automatic memory reclamation” subsystem is called the
>   garbage collector, or GC.)
>
> The reason for the pauses is that SpiderMonkey uses an old-school
>   stop-the-world mark-and-sweep collector

Vast improvements to Firefox's GC are planned but not yet implemented - see that link for more info.

Comment: Thanks, is there any moz webkit animation i can use to avoid this GC problem?

Comment: You could maybe look into [CSS Transitions][1]. I haven't used them in anger myself, and you'll need to provide a scripted fallback for older browsers. And for all I know they'll be affected by the GC. But there you have it ;)
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#AutoCompatibilityTable

Comment: In fact i've updated Firefox to the 8.0.1 version and no lag !!
It seems that GC is better managed in the latest version.
Thanks for your help again !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the inner workings of jquery, but I assume it's using a resize event for that div. Firefox handles resize events poorly, I'm not sure there's a way to fix it. Here's some more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize.html