# Why does jQuery UI's animate function lag in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

When I try to change the width of an element (a progressbar in my case) using the `animate` function of jQuery UI, the animation lags in FireFox. Every other browser animates it smoothly.

I'm really just using the `animate` function, but I create a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DeC3u/) so you can test it.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8227888/1394336), but this the comments mention a fix for this problem since FF 8, so the GC shouldn't be to blame any more.

Edit: I noticed that the lags happen very regular. Not always, but most of the time once per second. Maybe it **is** a GC-problem?

Comment: Because, sadly, Firefox is the new IE6. Just spent the last three hours trying to figure out why it was crashing only to find that a trivial CSS animation was burning an entire processor's worth of CPU, and throwing a native `confirm` box shot CPU to 126%. Yes, 126%. Conclusion: Screw Firefox until they stop screwing it up.

Comment: In FF30 anyway, the fiddle works perfect and smooth...

Comment: I noticed, that the lags are very regular (about once every second). Any ideas why this happens? GC? @Tallmaris: I had FF29.0.1 but did an update to 30 - the problem remains.

Comment: @Tallmaris Only on a reasonably free (and reasonably modern) CPU. Put any reasonable load and firefox starts choking (not just this animation, everything). I guess you can say that for any browser (any program, really), but FF just seems to be exceptionally bad at it.

Comment: This SO answer may help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227447/jquery-animation-on-firefox-7-0-1-lags

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing even on an i7 3rd gen CPU with 12 gb of ram (my dev PC) FireFox will choke trying to do a simple width animation, while Chrome and even IE have no problem. FireFox also will hang on functions that take more than a second to evaluate and throw "script not responding" error that I haven't seen since the early 2000s, while agian, Chrome and IE have no issue.

Conclusion: FF is bad.